# Why is $|x|/x^2=1/|x|$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

This may be a stupid question but I was looking over a proof and one of the steps simplifies  $|x|/x^2=1/|x|$ and I was wondering what the rigorous justification of that is. Is it because $x^2$ is essentially the same as $|x|^2$?

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: If you are speaking about real numbers (or their subset) then "yes". For complex numbers the equality $z^2=|z|^2$ does not generally holds.

Comment: I recommend viewing $|x|$ (for real $x$) as $\sqrt{x^2}$. It helps clarify this and other things without caaework.

Comment: Your tags were all wrong.  I added only the absolute value tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes!

For intuition, split into $2$ cases, $x$ positive and negative

Comment: This is a comment

Comment: sorry, @Gabrielek , should I delete this answer?

Comment: Nop. This is an answer to the OP's question, and not only is it correct but it even gives a recommendation on how to make it even more sure.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1570292)

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos This does provide an answer to the OP's question "Is it because...?", and it even gives an idea on how to show it.

Comment: I just have a request, please don't let this evolve into a flamewar cos ive seen that happen a lot on this site, it's just a small answer lol;

Comment: @Aditya_math this is an answer. Answers should be answers, not comments.

Comment: @DonAntonio You are right. I was fooled by that “For intuition”.

Comment: I think most of us are used to answers being more than two short lines...but in this case this one really is an answer to exactly what the OP asked. The OP didn't even ask "why is it that $\;x^2=|x|\;$ (for real numbers)?" . Thus, this is a short, on-the -point, answer. No war at all, just making things clear.

Comment: Thank you Mr.Antonio

Answer (score 2):

If $x\in\mathbb R$, then **by definition** of absolute value:

- If $x>0$, then $|x|=x$, which implies $$|x|^2=x^2$$
- If $x<0$, then $|x|=-x$, which implies $$|x|^2=(-x)^2=x^2$$

So, you can deduce that $$|x|^2=x^2$$ holds for all $x\in\mathbb R.$

Thus,

$$\frac{|x|}{x^2}=\frac{|x|}{|x|^2}=\frac{1}{|x|}.$$

Comment: I would add at the beginning $x\geq 0$ and then where you have written "Thus", I would put if $x\neq 0$.

Comment: @Sebastiano Yes, you are right I missed this point $\ddot\smile$